# Updating an Excel like a mobile app

Tags: vba, excel

I created an excel workbook to track inventory for a project that my wife is working on. It does a ton of useful things for her but I have so many other good ideas for it to do more. It has gained some attention from some of her friends and I would really like to share it with them but keep everything locked so that they cannot accidentally mess anything up. With that said, I want to keep developing it as I come up with improvements.

My question is, does anyone know a way that I can basically release versions of an excel just like a a code upgrade? I want to be able to pass this thing along and then when I make some improvements I can release them but nobody loses any data or has to copy and paste data. Would this be something I could accomplish with VBA? anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: I don't think there is any reliable way as the data may not work with the new improvements. Alternative could be Excel Online or Google Sheets where you can lock parts of the sheets and even modify them while someone is using it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apps can be easily updated because most of them have separate files for data, settings, user interface and functionality. In Excel usually all of that is combined in only one file, so it is very hard to separate them and update only the functionality without affecting the data. If you can figure out how to store the data in separate files, then updating would be easier.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem a few years ago.

I ended up using two VBA macros to automate data migration from the old version of the workbook to the new version. Here are the high level steps:

> ***Step 1:***
>
> Lock all of the cells except the inputs and options to the model so that you know where each piece of data is located (named ranges are helpful here).
>
> ***Step 2:***
>
> Write a VBA macro to scrape the values out of the unlocked cells and save them into a CSV with a particular format.
>
> ***Step 3:***
>
> Write another macro to load in the CSV you created in step 2 and fill those values in to the input cells.
>
> ***Step 4:***
>
> Add in a few buttons to your workbook so that your users can easily access both macros.

When your users want to upgrade from one version to the next they will export their data from the old workbook into the CSV and import it to the new workbook. There are more elegant solutions but in my opinion they aren't worth the extra effort to implement and maintain.

Depending on what you're doing Google Sheets could be a good alternative too!